# Email webform results - only filled fields

Tags: entities, webforms, emails

Is there a way to email the webform results with only the filled (NOT empty) fields
I don´t want all the fields to be mandatory and 80% of my long long form will be optional and it´s very wierd looking to have all those fields listed in the results, if the fields remain empty

Answer (score 1):

You could alter the webform email template to check for submission results before outputting them.

The documentation for utilizing the template is here:

http://drupal.org/node/1337488

Look under the Heading 'Using a webform email template'.